# Is Monero affected by the year 2038 / 2106 problem?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-wallet-cli, blockchain

Unix timestamps usually are stored as a 32 bit integer, either signed or unsigned which will [overflow either in 2038 or 2106](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). How are timestamps currently stored in Monero's codebase and blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unix timestamps usually are stored as a 32 bit integer...

They're usually 64 bit (in anything written this century).

> How are timestamps currently stored in Monero's codebase and blocks?

Unsigned 64 bit.

> Is Monero affected by the year 2038 / 2106 problem?

Not the core daemon or wallets, but that doesn't mean some *other* wallet or service *using* Monero hasn't made a mistake and is using only 32 bits for timestamps.

Comment: Well, Bitcoin seems to be affected and uses 32 bit integers. But good to know, Monero doesn't and other wallets should have enough time to fix their issues if they didn't yet.